# Select returns empty sockets list after a few messages from each client

Tags: python, sockets, tcp

I am trying to make a basic terminal-based chat application with python. I used select() to update readable/writable connections. After two messages from each client however, the server returns an empty readable list (sockets_list).

I already tried removing code that deletes connections from my sockets list.

this is server.py

```py
import socket
import select
import time

sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

# host, port
host = 'localhost'
port = 5555

# bind and listen for connections
sock.bind((host, port))
sock.listen(2)

print('Server started on. {} {}'.format(host, port))

# select lists
sockets_list = [sock]
outputs = []

clients = {}


def receive_message(conn):
    try:
        msg = conn.recv(4096)

        if not len(msg):
            return False

        return msg

    except conn.error as e:
        return False


while True:
    print('\n waiting for the next event')

    readable, writable, exceptions = select.select(sockets_list, outputs, [], 10)

    print(readable, writable)

    for s in readable:
        if s == sock:
            connection, address = s.accept()

            user = receive_message(connection)

            if user is False:
                continue

            sockets_list.append(connection)
            clients[connection] = user

            print(f'Accepted new connection from {user.decode()}')
        else:
            arr = s.recv(4096).decode().split(':')
            if len(arr) < 2:
                arr = s.recv(4096).decode().split(':')

            elif len(arr) >= 2:
                message = arr[1]
                # if message is False:
                #     print(f'Connection closed with {s}')
                #
                #     sockets_list.remove(s)
                #     del clients[s]
                #
                #     continue
                user = clients[s]
                print(f'Received message from {user.decode()}: {message}')

                for client in clients:
                    # But don't sent it to sender
                    if client != s:
                        # Send user and message (both with their headers)
                        # client.send(user['header'] + user['data'] + message['header'] + message['data'])
                        client.send(f"{user.decode()}:{message}".encode())
                        print(f'Sending {message} to {clients[client].decode()}')
```

This is client.py:

```py
import socket
import select
import errno
import sys

IP = "localhost"
PORT = 5555
current_user = input("Username: ")

client = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

client.connect((IP, PORT))

# client.setblocking(False)

username = current_user.encode()
client.send(username)

while True:
    message = input(f'{current_user} > ')
    if message:
        # Encode message to bytes, prepare header and convert to bytes, like for username above, then send
        client.send(f'{current_user}:{message}'.encode())

    try:
        while True:

            arr = client.recv(4096).decode().split(':')
            username = arr[0]
            if not username:
                print('Connection closed by the server')
                sys.exit()

            message = arr[1]
            # Print message
            print(f'{username} > {message}')
            message = input(f'{current_user} > ')

    except IOError as e:
        print(e)
        sys.exit()

    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
```

I expect the server to receive/send messages from both clients. Meaning whatever client 1 sent, client 2 will see.

Comment: One problem is that your server is not checking to see if your `recv()` calls return None.  `recv()` will return None when the TCP connection has closed, at which point you should close the TCP socket and remove it from `sockets_list`.

Comment: What is the point of doing that when the problem IS that its removing connections from the readable list. I added the code you wanted, it gives the same output.
```python
            if not data:
                print(f'Connection closed with {s}')
                s.close()
                sockets_list.remove(s)
                del clients[s]
```

Comment: The point would be to get to having a program that works correctly, I suppose.  If select() is returning an empty list of readable sockets, the most likely reason is that none of the sockets you passed in to its first argument are readable.

Comment: Sorry, I don't know much about the select module but why are the sockets not readable? It works fine for the first two messages, then it fails. Why do you think this is?

Comment: My first guess would be that your list might not contain the sockets your think it does (you can print out the list just before select() to be sure).  My second guess would be that your client isn't sending any data.

Comment: Thanks, your suggestions led me to the answer. The problem was the client. It wasn't sending/receiving properly. The server was fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was that I wasn't sending/receiving the data properly with the client. So I tweaked it a little bit and it works now!

```py
while True:
    message = input(f'{current_user} > ')
    if message:
        client.send(f'{current_user}:{message}'.encode())

    arr = client.recv(4096).decode().split(':')

    if arr:
        username = arr[0]
        message = arr[1]
        # Print message
        print(f'{username} > {message}')
```

Putting a forever loop in a forever loop didn't make sense so I got rid of it.

I checked if the client received data with `if arr:` and printed the data. Since arr was in the forever loop, it **ALWAYS** checked for data.

To send data, it was pretty simple, get input, send it via socket.